# linux x86-64 assembly output

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64

```
section .data
    msgr dw "bye"
section .text
    global _start
_start:
    lea ebx , [msgr]
    mov     rax, 1
    mov     rdi, 1
    mov     rsi, [ebx]
    mov     rdx, 3
    syscall

    mov    rax, 60
    mov    rdi, 0
    syscall
```

I checked this code with gdb. and i put "bye" to rsi.
but, no output.

i use linux 16.04 and nasm.

this command that i used.
`nasm -f elf64 asm.asm ; ld asm.o ;./a.out`

Comment: Use `strace` to see your mistake:  you're passing the contents of memory, instead of the pointer as the 2nd arg for `write()`.

Comment: Not a perfect dup target since it's 32-bit code using the `int 0x80` ABI, but it's the same thing really.  Doing `write(1, *(int64_t*)buf, 3)` instead of `write(1, buf, 3)`

Comment: wow thx peter. i will try it